# Cs50 edges filter is failing to process corner and edges pixels

Tags: cs50, edges

In the problem description, we were told to take outer pixels as having a value of "0".
I discriminate de outer pixels so as to do nothing with them, they won´t add a value, because multiplying by 0 gets 0.
I can´t seem to find where i went wrong. Can somebody give me a clue. Thanks a lot.
here is my code

```
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Make copy
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    double gxB, gxR, gxG, gyR, gyB, gyG;
    int GX[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int GY[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
    // Loop through pixels
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            gxB = 0;
            gxR = 0;
            gxG = 0;
            gyR = 0;
            gyB = 0;
            gyG = 0;
            // Loop through 3x3 box
            for (int row = (i - 1); row < (i + 2); row++)
            {
                for (int col = (j - 1); col < (j +2); col++)
                {
                    // Discriminate border pixels
                    if (exists(row, col, height, width))
                    {
                        gxR += copy[row][col].rgbtRed * GX[row][col];
                        gxG += copy[row][col].rgbtGreen * GX[row][col];
                        gxB += copy[row][col].rgbtBlue * GX[row][col];

                        gyR += copy[row][col].rgbtRed * GY[row][col];
                        gyG += copy[row][col].rgbtGreen * GY[row][col];
                        gyB += copy[row][col].rgbtBlue * GY[row][col];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gxR += 0.0;
                        gxG += 0.0;
                        gxB += 0.0;

                        gyR += 0.0;
                        gyG += 0.0;
                        gyB += 0.0;
                    }
                }
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = trimm(round(sqrt((gxR * gxR) + (gyR * gyR))));
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = trimm(round(sqrt((gxG * gxG) + (gyG * gyG))));
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = trimm(round(sqrt((gxB * gxB) + (gyB * gyB))));
        }
    }

    return;
}

bool exists(int ROW, int COL, int H, int W)
{
    if (((ROW >= 0) && (ROW < H)) && ((COL >= 0) && (COL < W)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }


}

int trimm(int x)
{
if (x < 256)
{
    return x;
}
else
{
    return 255;
}
}
```

Comment: What "problem description" are you referring to?

Comment: "And what about handling pixels at the edge, or in the corner of the image? There are many ways to handle pixels at the edge, but for the purposes of this problem, we’ll ask you to treat the image as if there was a 1 pixel solid black border around the edge of the image: therefore, trying to access a pixel past the edge of the image should be treated as a solid black pixel (values of 0 for each of red, green, and blue). This will effectively ignore those pixels from our calculations of Gx and Gy."

Comment: here is a link to the whole description. https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/4/filter/more/

Comment: it doesn`t shows in the code, but the functions are declared on top.

Comment: I tried multipling by zero, but check50 still expects diferent values for edge and corner pixels, the middle ones are passing fine.

Comment: I found the bug. Was in the way i was implementing the TRIMM function.